# Disabling sudo halt

Tags: zsh, alias

It's happened to me a few times now, that I want to shut down my own computer, grab the next best terminal (always have two dozen of them floating around), and type `sudo halt`, only to realize I've just shut down one of my servers because I didn't close the ssh connection I used half an hour ago.

I think the easiest way to tackle this would be to use my zshrc file to alias `sudo halt` to something else, depending on the hostname. I'm not sure whether you can use alias to do this, though. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a better solution would be to write a sudo rule that always requires a password to be entered for the 'halt' command.  That should provide a good check, especially if you have a different password on the production servers.

I think the sudoers entry would look like this, but you may need to consult the manpage:

ALL (LOCALHOST) = PASSWD: /sbin/halt

Answer (score 0):

The solution I use to avoid running commands in SSH hosts *unaware of where I am running it*, is to use a different prompt color when I ssh into another computer:

```
autoload -U colors && colors
if [[ $+SSH_TTY -eq 1 ]]; then
     prompt_color=%{$fg[green]%}
else
     prompt_color=%{$fg[red]%}
fi
# define your prompt here
export PROMPT="$prompt_color %U%2v%u %~ %# %{${reset_color}%}"
```